# Stream to youtube using Hardware Encoding

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently streaming to youtube using NVIDIA hardware encoding to reduce the load on the CPU, with this code:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -f gdigrab -i desktop -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v h264_nvenc -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/KEY"
```

My screen resolution is **2560x1080**, but this is the result i get in youtube:
[image]

There are huge empty spaces on both sides, and the resolution is not so good, even selecting  **"HD"** on youtube.

I tried to specify in the last parameter before `flv`,
`-s 2560x1080` but I could not see any difference.

Also would like to ask if someone knows what `-qp 0` does, I could not find it in the documentation, it does appear here:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop

Under hardware encoding.

Looking for any advice, taking in mind I'm trying to reduce the CPU usage and keep a normal/good resolution.

Comment: Copy and paste all of the text from the ffmpeg log.

Comment: Follow: https://pastebin.com/2bwgh7UR

Comment: @llogan any clue?

Comment: Not really. YouTube now wants a phone number for live streaming, and I don't want to do that, so I can't try it myself. Try giving it a normal size such as 1920x1080, and see if libx264 is better looking: `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -f gdigrab -i desktop -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -preset veryfast -g 60 -b:v 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 12000k -c:a aac -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/KEY"`